# Graphene bilayer rotation

Tags: graphics, version-7

How can we design the rotational picture of bilayer graphene using Mathematica 7.0 like in the figure? This gives Moire pattern[image]

Answer (score 16):

*Update*: I just noticed you wrote *Mathematica 7* and [`CirclePoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html) was introduced in v10.1.  I am updating my code to eliminate it.  I think what remains should work in v7; tell me if it does not.

This may need some tuning but it should give you a good start:

```
segment = Disk[#/2, 1/3] & /@ {{2, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, Sqrt[3]}, {-2, 0}};

layer = Translate[segment, Join @@ Array[{3 #, 1.76 #2} &, {10, 17}, 0]];

Manipulate[
  Graphics[
    {Blue, layer, Darker@Red, Rotate[layer, -θ]}
    , PlotRange -> {{-7, 35}, {-7, 35}}
    , ImageSize -> 500
  ]
  , {{θ, 0.55}, 0, Pi/2}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

This solution should work normally on Mathematica 7.

It first generates a hexagonal grid and then removes every third point. Finally two grids are combined in one figure.

I have fine-tuned the parameters to reproduce your figure.

```
range = Range[1197];
x = Mod[range, 31 + 1/2] 2/Sqrt[3.];
y = Quotient[range, 31 + 1/2] ;
allMeshPoints = Drop[Transpose[{x, y}], {3, -1, 3}];
disks = Map[Disk[#1, 0.35] &, allMeshPoints];

Manipulate[
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Lighter@Lighter@Blue, disks, Lighter@Red,
        Translate[Rotate[disks, angle], {dx , dy}]}],
    {{dx, 0.055}, 0, 0.3, 0.001},
    {{dy, -0.053}, -0.2, 0, 0.001},
    {{angle, -0.4839}, -1, 1, 0.001}
    ]
```

[image: graphene]